# Pattern Image Processing

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching

I am want to make a simple application that will detect a patterns on the wall like the image below.
[image: pattern]

So the patterns will be pasted on the wall. The camera will rotate around 360 degrees and identify the pattern.
I asked someone I know in the EEE field, and he said that i could use OpenCV. But he said OpenCV can only recognize 1 pattern only. Is this true.

I am new to image processing. I hope someone can advice me on how i should approach this project. If there are any valuable reference, please share. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If only these 4 patterns are there, I think finding its centroid would be sufficient. centroid will be more near to smaller leg of T.

Comment: can you share the test images? what do you mean "on the wall"?

Comment: The patterns will be printed and pasted on the wall. The webcam will be place on a robot which will find these patterns. 

So the main idea is to identify the patterns using image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it true but not quite. You need only one pattern on image to use methods like Surf. But you can use contour analysis to recognize pattern like your image. Also you can use AdaBoost to find your patterns if they are more complexity.

OpenCv is only library and have some methods to image processing. You can use what suits you best.

There are many tutorials about AdaBoost, Surf/Sift/Orb/Brisk... Contour analysis is more complex.

Good Luck!